# How do I suppress the error stream in the following batch file code

Tags: file, batch-file

I'm using the following code in a batch file to do copy all the MP3 files from a set of directories (that is always changing) to a specific location and then delete the mp3 files.  The code works, but most of the time there are no MP3 files to be found.  I'm trying to clean up what gets displayed in the batch window.  When there are no MP3 files to be found I always get a "file not found" message.  I'm trying to suppress the file not found.  The line that produces the error is the for /f "delims line (specifically the dir portion).  If I rem the copy and del lines I still get the error.  I tried putting >nul and 2>nul at the end of the dir statement first before the close quote, then in every position after.  Before the double quote and I still get the FNF but no other error, each position after I get an unexpected > error.

How can I suppress the error message in this statement?

```
set dSource=C:\Users\pc\Documents\Recordings\VOX
set dTarget=c:\recordings
set fType=*.mp3
for /f "delims=" %%f in ('dir /a-d /b /s "%dSource%\%fType%"') do (
    copy /V "%%f" "%dTarget%\" 2>nul
    del "%%f" 2> nul
)
```

Thanks,

Roveer

Comment: AFAICS you don't need `for /f` with `dir` here, just `for /r %%f in (%dsource%\%ftype%) do ...` should give the same list of filenames if any exist and no error message if none.

Comment: Dave, I did not find the same result when using your modified code.  I changed my example code (last line from del to dir and rem'd the copy) just to see what it would produce.  My code produces a list of the found files (just filename.ext).  The for /r %%f in (%dsource%\%ftype%) do ... code ran for a bit but produced no output.

Comment: Sorry; I had tested several variants but posted the wrong one. Try `for /r %dsource% %%f in (%ftype%) do ... something with %%f ...`

Answer (score 2):

```
for /f "delims=" %%f in ('dir /a-d /b /s "%dSource%\%fType%" 2^>nul') do (
```

The caret `^` "escapes" the `>`, telling `cmd` that it's part of the `dir` command (where it's valid), not the `for` (where it's invalid)

(same goes for `|` - often used for piping to `find/findstr`)

Comment: Oh I was so close!  I went looking after posting and found the ^ statement and tried it i must have not put it in the right place.  Thanks so much for your post.  It solved my problem.